# Dried beans, rice and oats, jerky, olive oil, salt, vitamins, electrolytes, water; anything else?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, astronaut-lifestyle, food, reduced-gravity-cooking, nutrition

If I don't worry about morale, would daily, average sized meals from the following be sufficient to stay alive for three years in space? I'm assuming only water is recovered from waste.

Assume enough electricity for cooking, zero gee pots and pans, ISS type kitchen equipment, spare parts for waste treatment hardware, and an routine waste dumps to space as needed.

- Dried beans
- Rice
- Oats
- Dried meat, fish, squid, etc. (if one partakes)
- Olive oil
- Salt
- Vitamins (+omega 3, 6)
- Electrolytes
- Powdered/dried seasonings
- Water

**edit:** For this mission, dried bulk items were chosen because they can potentially tolerate larger excursions in temperature for long periods of time. There are no freezers or refrigerators, and the mission may go inside Earth's orbit as well as way beyond, so keeping the food "outside" in the cold was not an option on his budget flight.

Comment: This diet is likely calcium deficient, at least.

Comment: Food like this would be extraordinarily difficult to cook properly in space.  There really isn't any facility on ISS that can boil water in a cooking fashion (boiling in a pot is heavily reliant on gravity-driven convection), which would make beans and oats tricky.  Powdered *anything* is an absolute no-go in space -- once spilled, it's almost impossible to clean up.

Comment: You are right. Calcium is not part of a typical vitamin pill, and the term electrolyte might not include nutritional quantities of chelated calcium.

Comment: Is anything really gained from having dry food and the water necessary to cook and eat it separately? Why not have "fresh frozen" food that's easier to cook, or just thaw and eat in case of some disaster with the exotic kitchen equipment. Or if they forget to send a cook.

Comment: @Tristan Oh, I remembered to specify "zero gee pots and pans"! This is a long transport mission, not much work, basically trying to keep busy to avoid going crazy. Cleaning up spilled powder might be an interesting challenge. The question is about nutrition. A question about cooking/preparation would be a different question.

Comment: @uhoh there's basically no such thing.  You'd need a sealed system that forces circulation while heating for a long period of time and doesn't get clogged by food debris.  To my knowledge, nothing of the sort has been invented, and it's doubtful it will be, as there are easier ways to meet long term nutritional needs.

Comment: @Tristan You don't know how is one thing. There is no such thing, and there could never be? That's extreme. Let's just say I know how. It's not that hard if you wanted to make one and clean it up after each use. Remember the ISS crew is extremely busy. The present astronaut needs to fill each day with something, so 1 hour for prep and 1 hour for tedious clean up after each meal is OK.

Comment: I didn't say there could never be.  I said there are easier ways to store and prepare food than what you're describing.

Comment: Infuse your seasonings in fluid to eliminate the powder problem. On shuttle: "Polyethylene dropper bottles contain bulk supplies of liquid pepper and liquid salt. The pepper is suspended in oil and the salt is dissolved in water. "

Comment: @Tristan you are right. Ergo [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21522/12102) :)

Comment: Some additional protein I think. Beans contain some protein and rice too. But an astronaut in space does not need so much carbohydrates to get enough protein from beans and rice only. Soybeans have more protein than usual dried beans.

Comment: To stay fit and strong during three years in space artificial gravity would be necessary to keep muscles and bones in shape.

Comment: @Uwe that's probably true, exercise alone does not seem to be sufficient in this case. I would not recommend doing this, but I don't think three years in zero gravity is known to be lethal by itself. Probably very bad, but it's not clear that it can kill you in three years, is it?

Comment: After three years in zero gravity, the astronauts should be able to work in gravity again, but without any help from others.

Comment: @Uwe is this a know fact, or just speculation? Isn't the longest continuous period for a human in microgravity *"only" about 1.2 years?* (only is in quotes because that is a really really long time in space!) Anyway, this question is about astronaut nutrition.

Comment: Related: https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jsts/21/2/21_2_27/_pdf

Comment: @uhoh vitamin/mineral pills may contain some calcium, but not enough (also of other minerals.  I've got [these](https://www.centrum.co.uk/products/centrum-advance/) at the moment (I wouldn't normally have something so fancy but the own brand were out of stock but these were on offer).

Comment: Keeping something on the outside of the spacecraft to keep it cool would work just fine, even inside earth's orbit. In space, things get hot when they receive (solar) radiation, and they cool down (a lot) when they are in the shade. Mercury, which has no atmosphere to retain heat, has a nighttime temperature of -173⁰C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fruit and vegetables** are two food groups missing from the list. Fruit could be processed and turned into a low moisture gel prior to travel. Something like [fruit rolls ups](https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/fruit-roll-ups), but with less sugar and healthier, or even a stiff jam as used for cooking or baking. [Dehydrated vegetables](https://www.harmonyhousefoods.com/Dehydrated-Vegetables_c_1.html) could be used, even dehydrated fruits.

**Protein** will be provided by both the beans and the dried meat or animal based seafood.

**Carbohydrates** will be provided by the beans, rice and oats. Another item that could be included, to offer a change from rice, is [couscous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couscous).

**Fiber** will be provided by the beans and oats and if *brown* rice is used instead of white rice, more fiber can be obtained from the rice. [Gut microbes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/gut-microbiome) need to be kept happy!

**Fats and oils** will be provided by the olive oil and the omega 3 & 6 supplements. Minor amounts may be obtained from the dried animal meats.

**Supplements** could provide the rest: vitamins, calcium, minerals, fatty acids, electrolytes & potentially sugar pills (or just some form of candy ;-), if one can be disciplined).

**Seasonings** should be liquid based to avoid messing the inside of the craft and contaminating equipment.

To reduce cooking times in space the rice could be partly cooked & vacuum sealed before going into space. The same would apply to couscous, if it were included. It would make things easier when cooking a "one pot mix" containing rice and dehydrated vegetables, etc.

In one of your comments you state, " I always considered vitamin pills to be an honorary member of the Fruits and Vegetables group". Personally I'd like something mixed in with the rice or oats (in porridge) for both flavor an bulk. I stand to be corrected on this, but I recall information a long time ago which stated that for good digestive system health bulk was required.

Tablets and supplements do not provide bulk, whereas re-hydrated vegetables and fruit will provide some bulk. In addition to assisting with scraping the walls of the digestive system and removing old cells, so of which could be malignant, bulk also provide [gut microbes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gut_flora) with a habitat.

The other thing with the digestive system is, yes the body does absorb some of the nutrients from the food that is eaten, but the gut microbes also consume some of the nutrients provided by the food & they convert them into something else our bodies require. It's a form of symbioses. For our own health and to avoid digestive system illnesses, such ulcerative colitis, we need to keep the gut microbes happy and a lot of tablets and very little bulk, isn't going to do that.

The [gut brain connection](https://www.health.harvard.edu/diseases-and-conditions/the-gut-brain-connection) needs to be considered as well, as [Gut Bacteria Can Influence Your Mood, Thoughts, and Brain](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/neuroscience-in-everyday-life/201908/gut-bacteria-can-influence-your-mood-thoughts-and-brain). With more than 100 million nerve cells lining the gut, more than in the spinal cord, the [enteric nervous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enteric_nervous_system), associated with the gut, is referred to as the [second brain](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/gut-second-brain/).

When it comes to providing food for a space flight crew, much more needs to be considered than just nutrition.

Comment: Thanks and `+1` for the great answer! I always considered vitamin pills to be an honorary member of the Fruits and Vegetables group. Of course we shouldn't do it, but couldn't a carefully prepared multivitamin provide everything nutritionally necessary so as not to suffer malnutrition for three years? I'm not saying it would be healthy or that it wouldn't increase risk of some diseases, but they would at least prevent space-scurvy and space-rickets, no?

Comment: @uhoh: as an after thought, I though the rice could be partly cooked & vacuum sealed before going into space to reduce cooking times in space. It would make things easier when cooking a "one pot mix" containing rice & dehydrated vegetables, etc. Regarding fruit & veggies in compressed powered form - supplement tablets, that would be possible, but personally I'd like something mixed in with the rice or oats (in porridge) for both flavor & bulk. I stand to be corrected on this, but I recall information a long time ago which stated that for good digestive system health bulk was required. ...

Comment: ... Tablets & supplements do not provide bulk, whereas re-hydrated veggies & fruit will provide some bulk. In addition to assisting with scraping the walls of the digestive system & removing old cells, so of which could be malignant, bulk also provide gut microbes with a habitat. The other thing with the digestive system is, yes the body does absorb some of the nutrients from the food that is eaten, but the gut microbes also consume some of the nutrients provided by the food & they convert them into something else our bodies require. It's a form of symbioses. For our own health & to avoid ...

Comment: ... digestive system illnesses, such ulcerative colitis, we need to keep the gut microbes happy & a lot of tablets & very little bulk, isn't going to do that.

Comment: As another after thought, there is the [gut brain connection](https://www.health.harvard.edu/diseases-and-conditions/the-gut-brain-connection) to consider as well.

Comment: The comments have been included in the answer.

Comment: I've taken home-cooked+dehydrated rice camping.  It saves fuel more than it saves time, as it takes a few minutes  to rehydrate in hot water, rather than longer and boiling or nearly.  It still takes longer to rehydrate than cooked+dehydrated lentil-based meals, but the dried beans would dominate cooking times (several hours at ambient pressure)

Comment: Ordinary dried fruit like raisins would also be helpful; combined with nuts in the form of trail mix you get something that's nice to eat and gives fat, protein+ micronutrients, without adding too much bulk or weight.  Nuts need careful storage to avoid going rancid, but vacuum would help.  They would be especially useful if meat wasn't an option, for [completeness of proteins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_protein) overall

Answer (score 2):

> If I don't worry about morale

This is where the list starts to go wrong. Psychological health is not somehow entire disconnected from the rest of the functions of the body. Severely limited ("boring") dietary options hurts morale in a major way, which has easily measurable physical effects on health.

What the list is missing is:

- Occasional variation items, rare treats, snacks, and varied choices.

*As an added bonus*, more variation dramatically reduces the chances of some important micro nutrient accidentally being overlooked.