# How much cargo volume is devoted to food

Tags: iss, food, supply-mission

On the ISS resupply missions go up about every 90 days or so. On those resupply missions how much volume and mass are devoted to food for the astronauts?

I've found estimates for the mass to be about 2.5kg/astronaut per day (that includes packaging mass). But, I can't seem to find any estimates for the volume of that cargo. For a crew of six, I've got a rough mass of 1350 kg. My guess is that's probably around a cubic meter or so, but that is a pure guess on my part.

Any help would be great, and if you have a source for the info that would be awesome too.

Comment: Packaging increases volume, I would guess around 1.5 cubic meter.

Comment: I've never seen the volume mentioned anywhere. I assume that's not a big of a worry as the weight of the cargo. You can Google the cargo manifest for flights and they'll give you a breakdown by weight. Depending on where you look you can get a better breakdown. This best place to reliable get a rough breakdown is https://www.nasa.gov/content/commercial-resupply-media-resources. It'll be under the mission overview.

Comment: Related: [Mass of food per astronaut per year for an extended deep space excursion?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24044/12102) Answer estimates "So per year, this gives about **191kg worth of food** and **44kg worth of packaging** (or 235kg overall)."

Comment: There is  a lot of packaging that drives up the volume.