# What happened to leftover food from the Shuttle program?

Tags: space-shuttle, food

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37470/26446) describes some of the food available during the Shuttle program.  **Was any pre-prepared food left over when the Shuttle program ended, and if so, what happened to it?**

---

Addendum: I have no interest in eating old food, thank you.  Just curious about what happened to it.

Comment: The new summary section in this 2014 revision of a Shuttle era document on nutrition in spaceflight says that the requirements placed upon food post-Shuttle were different, suggesting that they probably did not reuse most previous food. Of course, I can't rule out any reuse based on this source alone. https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/human-adaptation-to-spaceflight-the-role-of-nutrition.pdf

Comment: In addition to re-use inside NASA, it wouldn't surprise me if it was given to NASA employees, used in other government agencies, donated to museums as exhibits, or just simply sold as surplus.  But those are guesses.

Comment: After 9 years, left over food should not be eaten anymore. But tests of quality may be done.

Comment: @Uwe Wouldn't there be new food at the end of the period though that would have still been good for consumption immediately following the end of the program?

Comment: One wonders if the clear plastic Shuttle food packets (the ones that required water injection for rehydration purposes) were even compatible with ISS galley(s).