# What coatings are used for printed circuit board protection in space?

Tags: materials, electronics, manufacturing

Which coatings are better for printed circuit board (PCB) protection in space environment?

Comment: I would ask a PCB manufacturer with space experience.

Comment: Which environment?  Low earth orbit where it's more protected from cosmic rays?  Dusty surface of Mars or Luna?  High-radiation Jupiter? ...

Comment: It is interesting to know the most commonly used PCB coatings that are used in low and medium satellite orbits. But if you have information on the coatings used on geostationary satellites and interplanetary robotic vehicles, it would be great to share such information. In the countries of the post-Soviet space, urethane varnish is widespread, which is used to cover printed circuit boards (UR-231). I would like to know modern PCB coatings

Comment: Different but related: [What mitigation procedures are in place in space systems to prevent whisker growth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13473/12102) and [What are some common (but non-obvious) materials that are particularly unsuitable for spaceflight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25718/12102)

Comment: I clarified the question. My first thought when I see PCB is [Polychlorinated biphenyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychlorinated_biphenyl), not printed circuit board.

Comment: There are no corrosive gases or  liquids in space, so what protection is needed in space?

Comment: @Uwe:  Standard printed circuit boards are made of fiberglass and epoxy.  Vacuum could conceivably do nasty things to the epoxy.  Likewise, many components have plastic housings, or could have trapped air inside the sealed part.  Some integrated circuits have plastic housings that can absorb moisture.  Vacuum (or sudden pressure drops) could cause all kinds of havoc with those parts.  I assume the space industries have a grip on the problems and standards spelling out what you can use in space and what you can add for additional protection.

Comment: @JRE If the vacuum does nasty things to the epoxy, a coating could not stop it. The edges of a board are usually uncoated.